# Why php looping display variable name from sql database?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Why php looping display variable name from sql database ? I want to display the content of the username but it display the variable name

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
?>

<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?>

<h3>Messages</h3>

<?php include 'message_title_bar.php'; ?>
<br>
<div>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){
    echo "You can start New Converstion";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT 'id', 'username' FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($post=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $user = $post['id'];
        echo $post['username'];

    }
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what result do you get? Explain what you mean by display variable name

Comment: i want to loop display the content of username but it just display 'username' many times

Comment: what is the output of print_r($post); ? did you get all the record from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. Remove the `''` from the query. If you are dealing with SQL `reserved` words, use backticks to prevent errors. Take look at this [link about sql reserved words](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) . By default, you can add backticks to your column names just incase you mistakenly use a `keyword`

```
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `username` FROM users";
```

Comment: ooo tq so much i saw my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your SQL query statement.

I think you want your query string to look like this (remove the extra quotes around the column names):

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, username FROM users';
```

The results of your current SQL statement are not returning any values from the database table named `users`, but rather just the constant strings *id* and *username*.

Comment: ooo tq very much i saw my mistake